# Windows 8 HP laptop is stuck on mute

Tags: windows-8, laptop, audio, mute

Ever since I ran an automatic update a few days ago on my Windows 8 HP Envy dV6, my computer will not play sound.

The speaker button in the bottom corner says it's muted, but even when I adjust the volume and try to unmute it, it stays muted.

I've tried unmiting it through the Control Panel, through the Device Manager, to no avail. Does any have any other suggestions, or know how to revert the update?

Comment: uninstall and reinstall audio driver

Comment: I have the same problem and the same laptop. Did you find out how to fix it?

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-ENVY-dv6-Notebook-PC-series/5296055/model/5322702
Official website for drivers for specified notebook. You can try re-installing it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be, that you accidently muted with the hardware of the Laptop by pressing a combination with [FN] and the Loudspeaker Symbol.

According to the pictures of the keyboard I found: [FN] + F11

Comment: I ran it, it said the problem is that the Audio is muted :-( Yes, that is exactly the problem it's muted!

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. Fixed it by going to the Bang & Olufson app and unmuting there. That worked, after all of the other options failed. Good luck!